# how can I use StaggeredGridView in my project?

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-view, android-library

I downloaded StaggeredGridView from github https://github.com/bulletnoid/StaggeredGridView . I would like to use this View in my project. What am I have to do? I can not import it into eclipse as a library.

Comment: Create a project with that code and check the "is Library" flag on Properties -> Android. Then, add it as a library to your other project. You must have the library project always opened on your eclipse environment.

Comment: I create a project and marked "Mark This Project as a Library " box.Than I remove the marks from "Create Activity" and "Create custom launcher icon" boxes. When I went to the Properties-> Android for adding, I did not see the folder..

Comment: Creating the project: File -> New -> "Project..." -> Android -> Android Project from Existing Code -> Get the code downloaded. Then, go to Properties of that project -> Android -> mark the "is Library" checkbox. Then, with the project always opened on you eclipse environment get it on your other project as an existing library. Done.

Comment: when I select the folder.Eclipse give me an error which is "Select at least one project"

Comment: Are you downloading the project from this site: https://github.com/bulletnoid/StaggeredGridView/archive/master.zip . There is another way of adding the project you can do this: File -> Import -> Existing project into Workspace. Then, you only have to follow the other steps to make use of the library.

Comment: it says me that "No project found to import" according to your way

Comment: Create a project and call it "StaggeredGridView". Then, copy all the files in the code you downloaded to the folder where is the project you just created. Go to your eclipse and refresh the project. Then, check if the project have all the files you copied.

Comment: some of .java files have errors which is says "R cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: I have done it and also builted the project. I think this is not solution.